# Creating simple TCNT0 program ATMEGA 328 P-PU

Tags: atmega

I have a trouble with my beginner program for Arduino + ATMEGA 328 P-PU with tcnt0 in CTC mode, where I am using overflow made by OCR0A to make some visible delay. It looks, that counter is working somehow, because OC0A lit, however delay made with TOV0 or OCF0A doesnot work, because of "strange lit of apropriate diode". Could you help me to find mistake(s) in my program? Thanks all for help!

Btw: Do you know some good and verified debuger under Linux?

Program with mistakes:

```
            ; TCCR0 registers addresses
    .equ    tccr0a,     0x44
    .equ    tccr0b,     0x45
    .equ    tcnt0,      0x46
    .equ    ocr0a,      0x47
    .equ    ocr0b,      0x48
    .equ    tifr0,      0x35
    .equ    timsk0,     0x6E

    .equ    io_tccr0a,  0x24
    .equ    io_tccr0b,  0x25
    .equ    io_tcnt0,   0x26
    .equ    io_ocr0a,   0x27
    .equ    io_ocr0b,   0x28
    .equ    io_tifr0,   0x15

            ; PORT registers addresses
    .equ    pinb,       0x23
    .equ    io_pinb,    0x3
    .equ    ddrb,       0x24
    .equ    io_ddrb,    0x4
    .equ    portb,      0x25
    .equ    io_portb,   0x5

    .equ    pinc,       0x26
    .equ    io_pinc,    0x6
    .equ    ddrc,       0x27
    .equ    io_ddrc,    0x7
    .equ    portc,      0x28
    .equ    io_portc,   0x8

    .equ    pind,       0x29
    .equ    io_pind,    0x9
    .equ    ddrd,       0x2A
    .equ    io_ddrd,    0xA
    .equ    portd,      0x2B
    .equ    io_portd,   0xB

            ; SREG and STACK registers addresses
    .equ    sreg,       0x5F
    .equ    io_sreg,    0x3F

    .equ    sph,        0x5E
    .equ    io_sph,     0x3E
    .equ    spl,        0x5D
    .equ    io_spl,     0x3D

            ; Constants
    .equ    RAMEND,     0x8FF       ; End of SRAM for ATMEGA328P
    .equ    MILIS_VALUE,    0x7C        ; EDIT: FUCK THE TIME, TCNT0 HAS NO 128 PRESCALER, PRESCALER WILL BE 1024 JUST BECAUSE I WANT PREVIOUS COMMENT HAS NO MEANING NOW ---> ; Time in milisecond counted for 16MHz with 128 prescaler        





        .org    0   ; RESTART interupt vector
    rjmp    INITIALIZATION  ; Go to the start of the program

        .org    0x1C    ; TOV0 interupt vector
    rjmp    DELAY       ; Create visible delay from counter interval


        .org    0x34    ; Start the program right behind interupt vector table
INITIALIZATION:
    ldi r16,    hi8(RAMEND) ; High 8 bit value for SPH
    out io_sph, r16     ; Store SPH value to SRAM
    ldi r16,    lo8(RAMEND) ; Low 8 bit value for SPL
    out io_spl, r16     ; Store SPL value to SRAM
    clr r16         ; R16   = 0
    out io_sreg, r16        ; SREG  = 0

    ldi r16,    0xF0        ; Only high nibble is set
    out io_ddrc, r16        ; High nibble in PORTB is set as output because of possibility to check possible error with ease
    ldi r16,    0xF0        ; Byte for Output
    out io_ddrd, r16        ; Pin OC0A and other pins (PORTD.7-4 included) is set as output
    rcall   TOOGLE_LED      ; Inicialization LED and delay register(s) to the start condition

TCNT_INIT:              ; TCNT0 Initialization - not used label
    clr r16         ; Prepare value for counter stop, no FOC, third mode bit WGM2 is 0
    out io_tccr0b,  r16 ; Stop counter
    out io_tcnt0,   r16 ; Counting register = 0
    ldi r16,    0x42        ; Set OC0A to toogle and CTC mode for TCNT0
    out io_tccr0a, r16      ; Set control register a for timer 0
    ldi r16,    0x1     ; Interupt on TOV0
    sts timsk0, r16     ; Enable overflow interupt
    ldi r16,    MILIS_VALUE ; Count number for 125 count cycles
    out io_ocr0a, r16       ; Set top value for counter 0
    sei             ; Enable ingerupts globaly
    out io_tccr0b, 0x05     ; Set divisor to 1024, counter is running now!

MAIN_LOOP:
    rjmp    MAIN_LOOP       ; Infinite loop because of getting interupt from TCNT0

DELAY:                  ; TOV0 interupt subroutine
    in  r20,    io_sreg
    clr r21
    out io_sreg, R21
    inc r18
    cpi r18,    100
    brlt    END_DELAY
    out io_sreg, R21
    clr r18
    inc r17
    cpi r17,    100
    brlt    END_DELAY
    out io_sreg, R21
    clr r17
    inc r19
    cpi r19,    1
    brlt    END_DELAY
    rcall   TOOGLE_LED  
    out io_sreg, r20    
END_DELAY:
    reti    

TOOGLE_LED:
    ldi r17, 0x8        ; The highest bit of the lowest nibble is set for xor mask
    in  r16, io_portc       ; Get actual value of port B
    eor r16, r17        ; Toogle the highest pin of port B
    out io_portc, r16       ; write changed value to the port B
    clr r17         ; R17 = 0 <--- register is used for delay so it must be reseted
    clr r18         ; R18 = 0 <--- register is used for delay so it must be reseted
    clr r19         ; R19 = 0 <--- register is used for delay so it must be reseted
    ret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be senior programmer, before someone will answer here with help. ;-)

There are several mistakes in the code.

1) I shouldnot use TOV0 interupt, but I have to set OCIE0A in TCNT_INIT section, therefore use apropriate interrupt vector (what I partialy did in wrong code, because I have tested both, as you can see from old comment).

2) At the end of TCNT_INIT sequence I tried to run counter in CTC mode. It is absolutely wrong, because I put value into place, where address of register should be. Because 0x5 is value for register, it was sucesfuly compiled.

3) The most mean mistake - The interrupt vectors. I copied them directly from datasheet, so I thought, that they are absolutely correct. However after some looking for code examples, I saw very different numbers as interrupt vectors. Trouble was, that in datasheet is information that shows interrupts vectors, **BUT EACH ADDRESS IN FLASH POINTS TO TWO BYTES, SO ADDRESS FOR VECTOR FROM DATASHEET MUST BE MULTIPLIED BY TWO FOR ASSEMBLER.**

Code that should be working is enclosed below. Mistakes should be fixed. In addition there few lines, that could be erased, because they were used for testing.

Have a nice day.

```
            ; TCCR0 registers addresses
    .equ    tccr0a,     0x44
    .equ    tccr0b,     0x45
    .equ    tcnt0,      0x46
    .equ    ocr0a,      0x47
    .equ    ocr0b,      0x48
    .equ    tifr0,      0x35
    .equ    timsk0,     0x6E

    .equ    io_tccr0a,  0x24
    .equ    io_tccr0b,  0x25
    .equ    io_tcnt0,   0x26
    .equ    io_ocr0a,   0x27
    .equ    io_ocr0b,   0x28
    .equ    io_tifr0,   0x15

            ; PORT registers addresses
    .equ    pinb,       0x23
    .equ    io_pinb,    0x3
    .equ    ddrb,       0x24
    .equ    io_ddrb,    0x4
    .equ    portb,      0x25
    .equ    io_portb,   0x5

    .equ    pinc,       0x26
    .equ    io_pinc,    0x6
    .equ    ddrc,       0x27
    .equ    io_ddrc,    0x7
    .equ    portc,      0x28
    .equ    io_portc,   0x8

    .equ    pind,       0x29
    .equ    io_pind,    0x9
    .equ    ddrd,       0x2A
    .equ    io_ddrd,    0xA
    .equ    portd,      0x2B
    .equ    io_portd,   0xB

            ; SREG and STACK registers addresses
    .equ    sreg,       0x5F
    .equ    io_sreg,    0x3F

    .equ    sph,        0x5E
    .equ    io_sph,     0x3E
    .equ    spl,        0x5D
    .equ    io_spl,     0x3D

    .equ    mcucr,      0x55
    .equ    io_mcucr,   0x35

            ; Constants
    .equ    RAMEND,     0x8FF       ; End of SRAM for ATMEGA328P
    .equ    MILIS_VALUE,    0x7C        ; EDIT: FUCK THE TIME, TCNT0 HAS NO 128 PRESCALER, PRESCALER WILL BE 1024 JUST BECAUSE I WANT PREVIOUS COMMENT HAS NO MEANING NOW ---> ; Time in milisecond counted for 16MHz with 128 prescaler        





        .org    0   ; RESTART interupt vector
    jmp INITIALIZATION  ; Go to the start of the program

        .org    0x38    ; OCF0A interupt vector <--- IT LOOKS, THAT ADDRESSES FROM DATASHEET MUST BE DOUBLED BECAUSE OF CALL INSTRUCTION! SEE /usr/lib/avr/include/avr/iom328p.h ,io.h AND OTHER INCLUDE FILES! THIS INFORMATION MUST BE VERIFIED!
    jmp DELAY       ; Create visible delay from counter interval


        .org    0x68    ; Start the program right behind interupt vector table
INITIALIZATION:
    ldi r16,    hi8(RAMEND) ; High 8 bit value for SPH
    out io_sph, r16     ; Store SPH value to SRAM
    ldi r16,    lo8(RAMEND) ; Low 8 bit value for SPL
    out io_spl, r16     ; Store SPL value to SRAM
    clr r16         ; R16   = 0
    out io_sreg, r16        ; SREG  = 0
    out io_mcucr,   r16 ; MCUCR = 0

    ldi r16,    0xFF        ; Only high nibble is set
    out io_ddrc, r16        ; High nibble in PORTB is set as output because of possibility to check possible error with ease
    ldi r16,    0xF0        ; Byte for Output
    out io_ddrd, r16        ; Pin OC0A and other pins (PORTD.7-4 included) is set as output
    rcall   DELAY_INIT      ; Inicialization of DELAY subroutine

TCNT_INIT:              ; TCNT0 Initialization - not used label
    clr r16         ; Prepare value for counter stop, no FOC, third mode bit WGM2 is 0
    out io_tccr0b,  r16 ; Stop counter
    out io_tcnt0,   r16 ; Counting register = 0
    ldi r16,    0x42        ; Set OC0A to toogle and CTC mode for TCNT0
    out io_tccr0a, r16      ; Set control register a for timer 0
    ldi r16,    0x2     ; Interupt on OCIE0A
    sts timsk0, r16     ; Enable overflow created by OCR0A interupt
    ldi r16,    MILIS_VALUE ; Count number for 125 count cycles
    out io_ocr0a, r16       ; Set top value for counter 0
    sei             ; Enable global interupts
    ldi r16, 0x05       
    out io_tccr0b, r16      ; Set divisor to 1024, counter is running now!  <<<-------THERE WAS ANOTHER MISTAKE!!!!
;   in  r16, io_sreg            ; TEST ONLY !!!! SREG test, control of enabling interupts
;   out io_portd, r16           ; TEST ONLY !!!! SREG test, control of enabling interupts
;   sbi io_portc, 0         ; TEST ONLY !!!! Test of signal that DELAY subroutine was activated.    

MAIN_LOOP:
    rjmp    MAIN_LOOP       ; Infinite loop because of getting interupt from TCNT0

DELAY:                  ; TOV0 interupt subroutine
    in  r20,    io_sreg
    sbi io_portc, 0     ; Tell me, that this interupt was working one times at minimum!
    clr r21
    out io_sreg, R21
    inc r18
    cpi r18,    100
    brlt    END_DELAY
    out io_sreg, R21
    clr r18
    inc r17
    cpi r17,    1
    brlt    END_DELAY
    out io_sreg, R21
    clr r17
    inc r19
    cpi r19,    1
    brlt    END_DELAY
    rcall   TOOGLE_LED  
    out io_sreg, r20    
END_DELAY:
    reti    

TOOGLE_LED:
    ldi r17, 0x8        ; The highest bit of the lowest nibble is set for xor mask
    in  r16, io_portc       ; Get actual value of port B
    eor r16, r17        ; Toogle the highest pin of port B
    out io_portc, r16       ; write changed value to the port B
DELAY_INIT:
    clr r17         ; R17 = 0 <--- register is used for delay so it must be reseted
    clr r18         ; R18 = 0 <--- register is used for delay so it must be reseted
    clr r19         ; R19 = 0 <--- register is used for delay so it must be reseted
    ret
```